# If is_single in functions.php

Tags: functions, conditional-tags, the-content, wp-autop

I want the remove wpautop filter working only on posts from my blog.
Because at some pages i need the autop, and at some pages i need it to not be there.

I use the following rule and it is in my theme's functions.php:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
```

Because I only want it on blogposts I was thinking about an if statement, I searched the conditional tags page in Wordpress and found out I can use is_single .

But it doesn't work.

This is the code I use now.

```
if(is_single() ){
     remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
}
```

It is still wraped by an p.

And even if it would have worked, there is an other problem.
That is that is_single effects ALL singles from post types. And I only want the single of a blog post(posts).

Anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally it's not a common way to strip wpautop with remove_filter as it is native functionality of WordPress.

But if you want to : place the remove_filter() function right before the the_content() function on the pages/templates where you don't need the wpautop

`<?php remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' ); the_content();?>`

Answer (score 0):

I found it.

Really simple.

I just added the remove filter rule at the top of my document, above the header.
So now i have

```
<?php remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' ); ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
```